# DialogFlow in Fulfillment - DeepLink is not defined

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to use DeepLinks in Fulfillment Inline Editor in DialogFlow but I get  error "DeepLink is not defined". The question is how to import DeepLink into project?

more info about deeplink class:
[deeplink class](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_question.deeplink.html)

My index.js:

```
'use strict';

// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

// Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});


// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'favorite color'.
// The intent collects a parameter named 'color'.
app.intent('favorite color', (conv, {color}) => {
```

here I have error "DeepLink is not defined"

```
  conv.ask(new DeepLink({
    destination: 'Google',
    url: 'http://my.deep.link',
    package: 'my.package.name',
    reason: 'handle this for you',
  }))
})

// Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7",
    "dialogflow": "^0.1.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.4.1"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've go it! :) 
The line 4 should looks like:

```
const {dialogflow, DeepLink} = require('actions-on-google');
```